# solr increase number of digits that tint fields can store

Tags: solr, schema, tint

I have a `price` field of type `tint`, from which I will generate a `range facet`.
And I have now some items in my `index` that exceed `tint` type limit (max integer).
How do I increase `tint` `max integer value`?

Here is `tint` definition in `schema.xml`:

`<fieldType name="tint" class="solr.TrieIntField" precisionStep="8" positionIncrementGap="0"/>`

Do I have to increase `precisionStep=8`? because an error occured when trying to insert a number whose the `# of digits = 10`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot insert a integer value which is larger than Java's `Integer.MAX_VALUE` into a TrieIntField. Simply because it is a wrapper around it. You cannot do this. Technically not possible. Referring to [the documentation](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_6_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/schema/TrieIntField.html) possible is

> A numeric field that can contain 32-bit signed two's complement integer values.
>
> - Min Value Allowed: -2147483648
> - Max Value Allowed: 2147483647

Nothing more, nothing less.

---

You could switch to [solr.TrieLongField](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_6_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/schema/TrieLongField.html) instead, if the following limits are OK for you

> A numeric field that can contain 64-bit signed two's complement integer values.
>
> - Min Value Allowed: -9223372036854775808
> - Max Value Allowed: 9223372036854775807

Comment: Ok I have to turn `price` field to `tlong` type

Comment: btw `tlong` isnt compatible with `tint` so I have to reindex my data.

Comment: Yes that is true. You may however copy the value from the one field into the other field.

Comment: copy the `tint` field into a `tlong` copyfield?

Comment: Once a real big core would be live and you would have the data in Solr only, you can use a DataImportHandler with a [SolrEntityProcessor](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#SolrEntityProcessor) to write it back. But you would need a new field with a other name to make that work.